# 'css selector' is not supported for this session error in appium android native app test - Java

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, appium-android

I am getting this error in Java and I'm using java for testing android native app. This is what I'm doing

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
                (By.id("de.gymondo.app.gymondo:id/button_login"))).click();
```

Its weird as this code was working a few days ago but now its not. I didn't update Appium or Java sdk versions.

Comment: did you update the client libraries? like selenium libraries in code

Comment: nope i didn't...

Comment: Did you already found any solution?

Comment: Nope. I used x,y coordinates instead